# What are these dx dy coordinates of the watermark on the video?

Tags: xml, video, watermark

I have the following xml file of the text watermark of the video.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Layer1 Type="Text" PosType="LeftTop" DX="2.25" DY="2.02" ScaleInBG="0.159" Angle="0" Alpha="255">
    <WordArt TextEffect="4" TextColor="FFFFFFFF" bTextGradient="false" GradientColor="FF808080" ExtrudedText="false" OutlineColor1="FF000000" OutlineThickness1="4" OutlineAlpha1="255" OutlineColor2="FFFFFFFF" OutlineThickness2="4" OutlineAlpha2="255" bEnableShadow="false" ShadowColor="FF808080" ShadowThickness="4" ShadowAlpha="128" ShadowX="4" ShadowY="4" FontName="Arial" Height="-24" Weight="900" Bold="1" Italic="0" Underline="0">My watermark</WordArt>
</Layer1>
```

Can you please explain how dx, dy and ScaleInBg are calculated here? I try to find some document on Google to help convert it to left, top, width, height in pixels but not success. The screen is 720x1280px.
Thank you.

Comment: **(1)** _"...Watermark of the video."_ What video??? We cannot see visually what you mean by DX and DY of a logo. What has `Android` got to do with XML? **(2)** Did you try anything (experimenting with the numbers)? We need to know if you figured out a possible range (like it goes from _0.0_ to _100.0_ for maximum width of X-position)...

Comment: Well sorry my mistake. It's not for Android. The xml file is taken from Format Factory app for Windows. I must remove the program for I fear of it's not clean. I need to move the old configuration of the watermark to new app. Well the watermark above appears at the top left of the screen. When I increase dx it moved to the right and increasing dy it moved down to the bottom. Increasing ScaleInBG makes the text bigger. But I don't know how to calculate the thing. I did think that these dx dy is something common in computing. Hope someone can help.